# How to properly update input in unit test with React Testing Library + Vitest?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I am working on a project and am trying to unit test a simple state change for an input field. I keep getting a failed assertion when trying to simulate an onchange event using react testing libraries `userEvent.setup()` methods.

Test:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import CreateClientForm from '../../src/components/CreateClientForm';
import { vi } from 'vitest';

const mockProps: CreateClientFormProps = {
  clientName: '',
  setClientName: vi.fn(),
  clientEmail: '',
  setClientEmail: vi.fn(),
  clientPhone: '',
  setClientPhone: vi.fn(),
};

beforeEach(() => {
  render(
    <MockedProvider>
      <CreateClientForm {...mockProps} />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
});

describe('Create Client Form In Modal', () => {
  it('renders the correct initial input values', () => {
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Client Name:')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Client Email:')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Client Phone:')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('updates state values as a user types', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();

    const nameInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', {
      name: 'Client Name:',
    }) as HTMLInputElement;

    // Check initial value
    expect(nameInput.value).toEqual('');

    // Simulate user typing
    await user.type(nameInput, 'Johnny Bravo');

    console.log(
      screen.getByRole('textbox', {
        name: 'Client Name:',
      })
    );

    // Verify updated value after change event (FAILING HERE)
    //expect(nameInput.value).toEqual('Johnny Bravo');
  });
});
```

Related Component:

```
import LabelWithInput from './common/LabelWithInput';

const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};

const CreateClientForm = ({
  clientName,
  setClientName,
  clientEmail,
  setClientEmail,
  clientPhone,
  setClientPhone,
}: CreateClientFormProps) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <LabelWithInput
        label='Client Name:'
        type='text'
        id='clientName'
        value={clientName}
        onChange={(e) => setClientName(e.target.value)}
        className='form-control mb-2'
        data-testid='client-name'
      />
      <LabelWithInput
        label='Client Email:'
        type='text'
        id='clientEmail'
        value={clientEmail}
        onChange={(e) => setClientEmail(e.target.value)}
        className='form-control mb-2'
        data-testid='client-email'
      />
      <LabelWithInput
        label='Client Phone:'
        type='text'
        id='clientPhone'
        value={clientPhone}
        onChange={(e) => setClientPhone(e.target.value)}
        className='form-control mb-2'
        data-testid='client-phone'
      />
      <button className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CreateClientForm;
```

LabelWithInput Component:

```
import { type ComponentPropsWithoutRef } from 'react';

type LabelWithInputProps = {
  id: string;
  label: string;
} & ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>;

const LabelWithInput = ({ id, label, ...props }: LabelWithInputProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <input id={id} {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LabelWithInput;
```

Error in terminal:

```
 FAIL  tests/components/CreateClientForm.test.tsx > Create Client Form In Modal > updates state values as a user types
AssertionError: expected '' to deeply equal 'Johnny Bravo'

- Expected
+ Received

- Johnny Bravo

 ❯ tests/components/CreateClientForm.test.tsx:51:29
     49| 
     50|     // Verify updated value after change event
     51|     expect(nameInput.value).toEqual('Johnny Bravo');
       |                             ^
     52|   });
     53| });
```

I am using react 18. Relevant package json deps:

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "dom-testing-library": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6"
```

This is the output of the console.log of the input after "writing" to it:

```
<ref *1> HTMLInputElement {
  '__reactFiber$ryal2e46zro': FiberNode {
    tag: 5,
    key: null,
    elementType: 'input',
    type: 'input',
    stateNode: [Circular *1],
    return: FiberNode {
      tag: 5,
      key: null,
      elementType: 'div',
      type: 'div',
      stateNode: [HTMLDivElement],
      return: [FiberNode],
      child: [FiberNode],
      sibling: null,
      index: 0,
      ref: null,
      pendingProps: [Object],
      memoizedProps: [Object],
      updateQueue: null,
      memoizedState: null,
      dependencies: null,
      mode: 1,
      flags: 0,
      subtreeFlags: 1048576,
      deletions: null,
      lanes: 0,
      childLanes: 0,
      alternate: null,
      actualDuration: 0,
      actualStartTime: -1,
      selfBaseDuration: 0,
      treeBaseDuration: 0,
      _debugSource: [Object],
      _debugOwner: [FiberNode],
      _debugNeedsRemount: false,
      _debugHookTypes: null
    },
    child: null,
    sibling: null,
    index: 1,
    ref: null,
    pendingProps: {
      id: 'clientName',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      onChange: [Function: onChange],
      className: 'form-control mb-2',
      'data-testid': 'client-name'
    },
    memoizedProps: {
      id: 'clientName',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      onChange: [Function: onChange],
      className: 'form-control mb-2',
      'data-testid': 'client-name'
    },
    updateQueue: null,
    memoizedState: null,
    dependencies: null,
    mode: 1,
    flags: 1048576,
    subtreeFlags: 0,
    deletions: null,
    lanes: 0,
    childLanes: 0,
    alternate: null,
    actualDuration: 0,
    actualStartTime: -1,
    selfBaseDuration: 0,
    treeBaseDuration: 0,
    _debugSource: {
      fileName: '/home/sam/code/react_pro/mern_project_mgmt/client/src/components/common/LabelWithInput.tsx',
      lineNumber: 12,
      columnNumber: 7
    },
    _debugOwner: FiberNode {
      tag: 0,
      key: null,
      elementType: [Function: LabelWithInput],
      type: [Function: LabelWithInput],
      stateNode: null,
      return: [FiberNode],
      child: [FiberNode],
      sibling: [FiberNode],
      index: 0,
      ref: null,
      pendingProps: [Object],
      memoizedProps: [Object],
      updateQueue: null,
      memoizedState: null,
      dependencies: null,
      mode: 1,
      flags: 1048577,
      subtreeFlags: 1048576,
      deletions: null,
      lanes: 0,
      childLanes: 0,
      alternate: null,
      actualDuration: 0,
      actualStartTime: -1,
      selfBaseDuration: 0,
      treeBaseDuration: 0,
      _debugSource: [Object],
      _debugOwner: [FiberNode],
      _debugNeedsRemount: false,
      _debugHookTypes: null
    },
    _debugNeedsRemount: false,
    _debugHookTypes: null
  },
  '__reactProps$ryal2e46zro': {
    id: 'clientName',
    type: 'text',
    value: '',
    onChange: [Function: onChange],
    className: 'form-control mb-2',
    'data-testid': 'client-name'
  },
  _wrapperState: { initialChecked: undefined, initialValue: '', controlled: true },
  '__reactEvents$ryal2e46zro': Set(1) { 'invalid__bubble' },
  value: [Getter/Setter],
  _valueTracker: {
    getValue: [Function: getValue],
    setValue: [Function: setValue],
    stopTracking: [Function: stopTracking]
  },
  setSelectionRange: [Function: intercept] {
    [Symbol(Interceptor for programmatical calls)]: Symbol(Interceptor for programmatical calls)
  },
  selectionStart: [Getter/Setter],
  selectionEnd: [Getter/Setter],
  select: [Function: intercept] {
    [Symbol(Interceptor for programmatical calls)]: Symbol(Interceptor for programmatical calls)
  },
  setRangeText: [Function: intercept] {
    [Symbol(Interceptor for programmatical calls)]: Symbol(Interceptor for programmatical calls)
  },
  [Symbol(Last check for pointer-events)]: {
    '1': {},
    '2': {},
    result: { pointerEvents: 'auto', tree: [Array] }
  },
  [Symbol(Displayed selection in UI)]: { anchorOffset: 0, focusOffset: 0 },
  [Symbol(Node prepared with document state workarounds)]: Symbol(Node prepared with document state workarounds),
  [Symbol(Initial value to compare on blur)]: '',
  [Symbol(Displayed value in UI)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(Track programmatic changes for React workaround)]: undefined
}
```

As you can see, the `value` property is still ''...so maybe the `await user.type()` is not actually working?

I just want to assert that the input's value properly updates when a user types something.

Why won't this pass?

Thanks!

---

UPDATED W/ Answer thanks to @TaiweiTuan's answer.
Final Test File Code:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import CreateClientForm from '../../src/components/CreateClientForm';
import { useState } from 'react';

// Create a mock Parent component:
const MockParentComponent = () => {
  const [clientName, setClientName] = useState('');
  const [clientEmail, setClientEmail] = useState('');
  const [clientPhone, setClientPhone] = useState('');

  return (
    <MockedProvider>
      <CreateClientForm
        clientName={clientName}
        setClientName={setClientName}
        clientEmail={clientEmail}
        setClientEmail={setClientEmail}
        clientPhone={clientPhone}
        setClientPhone={setClientPhone}
      />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
};

beforeEach(() => {
  render(
    <MockedProvider>
      <MockParentComponent />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
});

describe('Create Client Form In Modal', () => {
  it('renders the correct initial input values', () => {
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Client Name:')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Client Email:')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Client Phone:')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('updates state values as a user types', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();

    const nameInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', {
      name: 'Client Name:',
    }) as HTMLInputElement;

    // Check initial value
    expect(nameInput.value).toEqual('');

    // Simulate user typing
    await user.type(nameInput, 'Johnny Bravo');

    console.log(
      screen.getByRole('textbox', {
        name: 'Client Name:',
      })
    );

    // Verify updated value after change event
    expect(nameInput.value).toEqual('Johnny Bravo');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely speculating but look like --

1. In this part

```
screen.getByRole('textbox', {
  name: 'Client Name:',
}
```

I do not see if the input boxes are given a `role=textbox` in your `CreateClientForm` and your `LabelWithInput`, so it could be jest actually unable to find the element of that role. However, the fact that jest can assert the field is empty, then its probably working fine. Do play around with it if the next one still fails. And speaking of the next one...

2. In your `beforeEach` block, you are passing mocked props `mockProps` to the `CreateClientForm` component, rendering these `setClient...` useless due to it being an mocked/empty function as you test the typing into the input field.

(Updated)

In this case, either create a test component that has the same `useState` the parent component of `CreateClientForm` --

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [clientName, setClientName] = useState('')
  const [clientEmail, setClientEmail] = useState('')
  const [clientPhone, setClientPhone] = useState('')
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    return
  }

  return (
    <MockedProvider>
      <CreateClientForm
        clientName={clientName}
        setClientName={setClientName}
        clientEmail={clientEmail}
        setClientEmail={setClientEmail}
        clientPhone={clientPhone}
        setClientPhone={setClientPhone}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    </MockedProvider>
  )
}
```

So then in your test you can

```
it('updates state values as a user types', async () => {
  render(<TestComponent />)
  //... rest of the code
```

Cheers.

Comment: If I don't mock the props I get a TS error: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'CreateClientFormProps': clientName, setClientName, clientEmail, setClientEmail, and 2 more..

Also, textbox is the default role of input here and all tests pass if I comment out the last assertion:  ✓ tests/components/CreateClientForm.test.tsx (2)
 ✓ tests/components/Clients.test.tsx (3)
 ✓ tests/components/CreateClientModal.test.tsx (3)
 ✓ tests/components/Header.test.tsx (1)
 ✓ tests/components/ClientRow.test.tsx (3)

 Test Files  5 passed (5)
      Tests  12 passed (12)

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with async vs sync and it may be looking for the input's value too quickly...but I already have await user.type so I am not sure what else to try

Comment: Updated the answer with more context! Please take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: That was the issue...incorrectly mocking the props. It needed a simulated parent component to pass it down.